# How to convert a .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5 assembly into a self contained binary as a post process?

Tags: .net-core, .net-assembly, .net-5, .net-core-3.1

I release some of my applications (.NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0; we talk about applications, not libraries) as commercial software. Therefore, I make it a little bit harder for crackers to understand and patch-out my licensing logic by (not only) using a code obfuscator. The obfuscator takes a fully managed code .NET assembly, and produces a "protected" fully managed code .NET assembly. The obfuscator cannot handle a self contained binary, as produced with `dotnet publish --self-contained` ([dotnet publish documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)).

I want to produce self contained binaries for various targets (macOS, Linux, Windows), because some customers don't want to install the .NET runtime, but, on the other hand, are totally fine, when the .NET runtime is part of the self contained binary.

Now I am wondering, whether it is possible to take the "protected" but still full managed code .NET assembly and convert this into an self contained binary. And if so, how to do it?

I would rather not like to decompile the protected assembly and recompile it again, but I keep this option in mind when there is no other solution available.

Current workflow:

1. Write source code.
2. Build the .NET assembly (`dotnet build`).
3. Run the obfuscator against the .NET assembly.
4. Release the software (as fully managed code .NET assembly, which requires the .NET runtime to be installed on the target systems).

Desired workflow:

1. Write source code.
2. Build the .NET assembly (`dotnet build`).
3. Run the obfuscator against the .NET assembly.
4. **Make the protected .NET assembly a self contained binary.**
5. Release the software (as self contained binary, which does not need the .NET runtime, as it already contains it itself).

Comment: Is the question if it's possible to take the output of `dotnet publish` and run another command on it that would generate the output of `dotnet publish --self-contained`? If so, no, nothing through the `dotnet` CLI at least

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I have edited my question, is it more understandable now? I use `dotnet build` to generate a .NET assembly, which I then protect using the obfuscator, which produces a .NET assembly similar to `dotnet build`. Now I want to convert that .NET assembly into something which reassembles `dotnet publish --self-contained`.

Comment: From what I see, there's nothing else that mimicks what `dotnet publish --self-contained` does. This is a long shot, but what if you did `dotnet publish --self-contained` and replaced your assembly(ies) with the obfuscated version?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I haven't had really digged into the self contained variant, but can it be really that simple, that it is just the .NET runtime with the .NET assembly, a bootstrapper, a header to let the bootstrapper known where the assembly is located, and the unmodified (by `dotnet publish --self-contained`) .NET assembly itself? When this is true, a simple Batch/PowerShell post-process could do the trick (replacing the assembly and fixing the header). Do you mean this?